# Java - Splitting String

Tags: java, split

I'm trying to split a date string in the format of day.month.year

The code i'm using is

```
String[] dates = date.split(".");
```

For the input string "24.05.21" i'd expect to get a dates.length of 3, but i'm getting 0

Full code

```
System.out.println("codesList:" + codesList.get(0));
            String date = codesList.get(0).replace("Codes ", "");
            System.out.println("Date:" + date);
            String[] dates = date.split("."); // day . month . year
            System.out.println("Dates:" + dates.length);
```

> codesList:Codes 24.05.21
>
> Date:24.05.21
>
> Dates:0

Comment: `split` expects a regex. `.` means any character. Escape it like `\\.`.

Comment: Do you have to use `String.split(...)` or would you accept something else, like parsing the date `String` instead of splitting it?